# Google maps api v3 geocoder viewport

Tags: google-maps, viewport, google-geocoder

when I enter a location (city or country) and an infowindow is open the following code will only find locations within the area of the open infowindow:

```
function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
         } else {
    alert("Sorry, we couldn't find the location for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

}

I want to zoom to the location viewport WITHOUT the fitBounds

This kind of works:

```
map.setZoom(13);
```

But I don't want to specify the zoom level

Here's a link from the latter code: http://www.hostelbars.com/map_test_v3_3.html

I'd appreciate some help - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to constrain the geocoding to the bounds of the visible map, rather than the open infowindow?

You need to tell the geocoder about your desired bounds in the request not when handling the result.

Refer to http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderRequest

Set the bounds in the geocoderRequest to map.getBounds().